# Windows Service with Autofac Holds onto References

Tags: c#, memory, out-of-memory, autofac

We are in the middle of attempting a drop-in replacement of Autofac for Ninject in our windows service (before potentially making more enhancement to take care of Autofac features), but are running into a memory issue.

Here's a contrived example that doesn't reproduce our issue, but demonstrates the current layout of the app:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            var ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[10000000]);
            var ms2 = new MemoryStream(new byte[10000000]);

            builder.RegisterType<BaseRepo>()
                .WithParameter("ms", ms)
                .As<IBaseRepo>();

            builder.RegisterType<DerivedRepo>()
                .WithParameter("ms", ms2)
                .As<IDerivedRepo>();

            builder.RegisterType<BaseFactory>().As<IBaseFactory>();
            builder.RegisterType<Derived>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<Derived>().Keyed<Base>(BaseEnum.Derived).As<Base>();

            var container = builder.Build();

            var factory = container.Resolve<IBaseFactory>();

            while (true)
            {
                var instance = factory.Create(BaseEnum.Derived);
                instance.DoSomething();
                instance.Dispose();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IDerivedRepo : IDisposable {}

    public class DerivedRepo : IDerivedRepo
    {
        private readonly MemoryStream _ms;

        public DerivedRepo(MemoryStream ms)
        {
            _ms = ms;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _ms.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public interface IBaseRepo : IDisposable {}

    public class BaseRepo : IBaseRepo
    {
        private readonly MemoryStream _ms;

        public BaseRepo(MemoryStream ms)
        {
            _ms = ms;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _ms.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public enum BaseEnum
    {
        Derived = 1
    }

    public interface IBaseFactory
    {
        Base Create(BaseEnum baseEnum);
    }

    public class BaseFactory : IBaseFactory
    {
        private readonly IComponentContext _componentContext;

        public BaseFactory(IComponentContext componentContext)
        {
            _componentContext = componentContext;
        }

        public Base Create(BaseEnum baseEnum)
        {
            return _componentContext.ResolveOptionalKeyed<Base>(baseEnum);
        }
    }

    public interface IDisposableThing : IDisposable
    {
        void DoSomething();
    }

    public abstract class Base : IDisposableThing
    {
        protected readonly IBaseRepo BaseRepo;

        protected Base(IBaseRepo baseRepo)
        {
            BaseRepo = baseRepo;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disposing base");
            BaseRepo.Dispose();
        }

        public abstract void DisposeChildren();

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing something");
        }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        private readonly IDerivedRepo _derivedRepo;

        public Derived(IBaseRepo baseRepo, IDerivedRepo derivedRepo) : base(baseRepo)
        {
            _derivedRepo = derivedRepo;
        }

        public override void DisposeChildren()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disposing derived");
            _derivedRepo.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Basically, we--at regular intervals--use a factory to instantiate an instance of an abstract class based on an enum value, do some work with that instance, then dispose of it. The problem is that those instances are not getting cleaned up by the garbage collector and the memory usage of the app increases steadily, with DebugDiag2 reporting that it is holding onto instances of the equivalent of our `MemoryStream` members in our repos (in our real app, these are wrappers over Entity Framework `DBContext`), with no other references to our code reported in its analysis so I have nothing else to go on.

I know there probably isn't enough here to give a definitive answer, what I'm more looking for is suggestions on where we are obviously doing something wrong (the whole team is new to Autofac and I know we are using the service locator anti-pattern, but I assume that isn't causing the problems we are seeing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you experience is normal as Autofac keeps track, within a lifetime scope, of objects it resolves. These will be disposed when the associated lifetime scope is itself disposed. In your case, you only have **one** lifetime scope, the one created when you build the container from the builder.

I suggest that you have a good read of [this documentation page](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/) which explains more in detail how lifetime scopes work.

A starting point would be to create an inner lifetime scope every time you start new work within the regular interval. It could look something like this:

```cs
var container = builder.Build();

while (true)
{
    // Create an inner lifetime scope that will keep track of every
    // object it creates
    using (var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        // resolve objects from `lifetimeScope`
        // do work with them
    }
    // At the end of the using directive, lifetimeScope will be disposed
    // and will dispose with it any objects it kept track of

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```